# How do the thread local variables in the Rust standard library work?

Tags: multithreading, rust, thread-local, thread-local-storage

How do the [thread local variables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.thread_local.html) in the Rust standard library work? I looked at [the code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/618b01f9fa0a6b4e7e2ce5b3409abe104b80c4a8/src/libstd/thread/local.rs), but got lost in indirection. It seems that there are different configurations for thread local storage, an OS dependent mode and a fast mode. Which one is the default, and how do I choose which one to use? In particular, what are the implications of using thread local storage in a crate for the user of the crate?

Using thread local storage is simple enough, and the [generated assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/MZDnX4) looks really efficient, but I can not use the feature in a library without fully understanding the implications.

I've also asked:

- [How many bytes will a thread local variable in Rust use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58942482/155423)

Comment: Did you click through to the suggested reading of [`LocalKey`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.LocalKey.html)? It states: *This key uses the fastest possible implementation available to it for the target platform* and *Initialization is dynamically performed on the first call to with within a thread, and values that implement Drop get destructed when a thread exits* which appear to answer both of your questions.

Comment: Yes, of course I read that. That tells me what it does and that it tries to be fast, but not *how* it works. E.g. it does not help me answer the question how many bytes per thread it will cost library users if I use a thread local in a library...

Comment: The current close vote is "Too broad — Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer". You have indeed asked a very broad question ("how is something implemented") and have actually asked multiple questions (+ "which is default" + "how do I choose" + "what are the implications" + "how much space does it take"). Any answer that covered these topics to a thorough degree would be a chapter in a book, which is a pretty good sign that the question is overly broad.

Comment: No idea about the title though; the only similar thing I've seen personally is a warning that specific titles have historically been downvoted for being low-quality. As you've seen, I was able to edit it (and I bet you could have too).

Comment: If I ask a concrete question it probably will be closed because it can not be simply answered. But I will try it anyway. But in another question... Feel free to close this one...

Comment: Of the ones I've identified, "what is the space overhead of using a thread local" seems reasonable and answerable. However, because there are platform-specific details, it may indeed be very hard to answer, but should be on-topic. It would probably be good if you identified a base set of platforms you were interested in (e.g. 64-bit Mac/Linux/Windows).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202676/discussion-between-rudiger-klaehn-and-shepmaster).

Comment: As far as i remember, rust threadlocals based on pthreads (for linux) library. So, the overhead same as pthreads. See manual for pthread_key_creatre() and others.

Answer (score 14):

The different configurations you see are related to `#[thread_local]`, a feature that is intended to replace the `thread_local!` macro to make the user code more straightforward, e.g.:

```rust
#![feature(thread_local)]

#[thread_local]
pub static mut VAR: u64 = 42;
```

However, at the moment of writing, this feature is not fully implemented yet (you can find the tracking issue [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29594)). It *is* used internally in the compiler code though, and that is the magic you see in the actual 'fast' [implementation in `std::thread::LocalKey`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a51e004e1bf7f9bba151dd9104a217c1ace6a0a2/src/libstd/thread/local.rs#L160-L166):

```rust
#[thread_local]
#[cfg(all(
    target_thread_local,
    not(all(target_arch = "wasm32", not(target_feature = "atomics"))),
))]
static __KEY: $crate::thread::__FastLocalKeyInner<$t> =
    $crate::thread::__FastLocalKeyInner::new();
```

Notice the `#[thread_local]` attribute at the top. It is then translated down to LLVM IR, so the actual implementation of TLS (thread-local storage) is [carried by LLVM](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#thread-local-storage-models) and implements the [ELF TLS models](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/tls.pdf). This is the default configuration.

> how do I choose which one to use?

You'll need to compile your own `rustc` version with the `target_thread_local` feature omitted. In that case, the [`os` variant](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a51e004e1bf7f9bba151dd9104a217c1ace6a0a2/src/libstd/thread/local.rs#L465) of `std::thread::LocalKey` will be used, and then, depending on a platform, it can use [pthreads (Unix)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a51e004e1bf7f9bba151dd9104a217c1ace6a0a2/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread_local.rs), or [Windows API](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a51e004e1bf7f9bba151dd9104a217c1ace6a0a2/src/libstd/sys/windows/thread_local.rs), or something else.

WebAssembly is a special case: as it doesn't support threads, TLS will be translated down to simple static variables.